# Why would Pending transactions disappear?

Tags: metamask, nethereum, polygon

I've been working on integrating with the Polygon blockchain programmatically (using Nethereum) but my contract interactions and send transactions all appear to be pending, then when I search for them again a few minutes later they no longer exist.

[image]

I assume they are failing / being rejected for some reason, but I have no idea what that reason is.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Miners decide how long they keep pending/queued transactions. If they disappear on polygonscan, it only means that polygonscan no longer has it, but other miners could still have them.

There are three main reasons why your transactions are not validated:

### Gas price too low (pending)

The gas price of your transaction is lower than the lowest gas price accepted by miners. You can fix that by replacing the transaction with a higher gas price (at least 10% higher).

### Missing nonce (queued)

In a sequence of transactions, a nonce is missing. For instance, that could happen if you sent transactions with nonce 0, 1, 3, 4 and 5. In such a case, transactions 0 and 1 would be mined, but 3, 4 and 5 would not (they would be queued) because 2 is missing.
To fix this, simply broadcast a transaction with nonce 2.

### Nonce already mined (rejected)

If transaction of nonce X has already been mined, you cannot send another transaction from the same address with nonce X. It will be rejected.

Comment: This was very helpful, thankyou.  My issue was because my nonce number was off.